# Starting the loop cycle from current month in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with rainfall amount for each month. I am doing some calculation in a foreach loop which starts from 0 index in the array. How can I start from the current month (say 4th month) and end at third month next year? Below is the code I have in hand.

```
public static function getWaterLevels($params)
{
    $rainfall = $params["rainfall"];
    $currentTime = Carbon::now();
    $currentMonth = $currentTime->month;
    $volume = 0;
    $demand = $params["household_number"] * 140 * 30;
    $tankSize = $params["tank_capacity"];
    $waterLevels = array();
    foreach ($rainfall as $amount){
        $runoffAmount = 0.80 * ($amount - 2) * $params["roof_area"];
        $volume = $volume + ($runoffAmount - $demand);
        if ($volume > $tankSize)
        {
            $overflow = $volume - $tankSize;
            $deficit = 0;
            $volume = $volume - $overflow;
        }
        elseif ($volume < 0)
        {
            $deficit = abs($volume);
            $overflow = 0;
            $volume = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            $overflow = 0;
            $deficit = 0;
        }
        array_push($waterLevels, array(
            "volume" => $volume,
            "overflow" => $overflow,
            "deficit" => $deficit
        ));
    }
    return $waterLevels;
}
```

In the above function, I want to start the loop at $currentMonth - 1. The structure of rainfall array is like this:

```
array:12 [
  0 => 59
  1 => 57
  2 => 54
  3 => 76
  4 => 76
  5 => 87
  6 => 82
  7 => 83
  8 => 88
  9 => 91
  10 => 84
  11 => 74
]
```

Comment: maybe try + 11 months?

Comment: Could you `print_r($rainfall)` to see the structure of array?

Comment: I don't understand why you need the start and the end? How it's gonna be the end? If it starts from 4rth month, which is going to be the 3rd month of "next year"

Comment: `foreach ($rainfall as $month => $amount){` if you want to get the month (it starts from 0)

Comment: The reason for the function is I need water levels in the tank for the next twelve months starting from the current month. The loop should be like this. (4,5...12,1,2,3)

Comment: What is the exact desired output?